How do I infer sex from a VCF file?
I have human samples VCF files that I want to infer the sex of. I do not have sequencing information or information about coverage. What's the best way to go about this? I'm looking for a robust and reliable method. Tools are okay, and conceptual or algorithmic ideas about what to do are also okay.

try somalier: https://github.com/brentp/somalier
https://genomemedicine.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13073-020-00761-2 :

The sites files include informative variants on the X and Y chromosomes so that Somalier can also estimate a sample’s sex from the genotypes.

